# relations and trichotomy

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Is it true if there is a relation $R$ on A and $(x,x) \in R$ for some $x \in A$ then the relation does not have trichotomy?

For instance if $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$

$R=\{(d,c),(c,a),(b,d),(d,a),(a,a),(b,c),(b,a)\}$ does $R$ not have trichotomy since $(a,a) \in R$?

Or does it have trichotomy?

I was just asked the following question.

(T/F) If $(x,x)\in R$ for some $x \in A$ the $R$ does not have trichotomy.

The answer was true and I am confused?

Comment: Look for instance at <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)>. Check out the first sentence in the properties.

Comment: I have seen this page before and it seems like for this particular case $\forall a,b,c,d \in A$ that either $aRb$,or $bRa$, or $aRa$. Also I am more confused because this question was asked on stack exchange and someone said that the relation $does$ have trichotomy

Comment: Just follow the definition carefully. Given any $x$ and $y$, exactly one of those holds: $xRy$ or $yRx$ or $x=y$. In particular, if $x=y$, then neither is $xRy$ true nor is $yRx$ true.

Comment: @Malkoun Sorry I read the wrong section.It seems in this case that $R$ is irreflexive, asymmetric, but not semi-connective, making the relation lack trichotomy.Is this a correct interpretation? I'm also really confused about semi-connectivity.Does this mean a relation can only be trichotomous if it relates distinct elements, once and only once, and also must relate every distinct element to each other element?

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, if $R$ has trichotomy, then it follows that $xRx$ is false, no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: It is a problem done in lecture that I was having

Comment: One more question, so $R-\{(a,a)\}$ would have trichotomy?

Comment: yes. When you remove $(a,a)$ from $R$, it then has trichotomy. Just check the definition. Essentially, you have a total ordering on the $4$ letters, namely: $b<d<c<a$.

Comment: The main thing that is confusing me is how to interpret $a=a$ in the definition does this just mean that a is not related to itself? How would you interpret the $a=a$ part of a relation has trichotomy iff $aRb,bRa$,or $\textbf{a=a}$

Comment: I think I see what confuses you. $=$ itself is a binary relation. But a binary relation could even be empty, which means that no two elements are related. In particular, for no $x$ is $xRx$ true, if $R = \emptyset$. Welcome to the joys of logic :). Read the definitions very carefully, and do not make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is trichotomous iff for any $x$ and $y$: exactly one of $xRy$, $yRx$, or $x=y$ holds.

So, if you pick $x=y$, that means that for any $x$: exactly one of $xRx$ or $x=x$ holds.

But of course we always have $x=x$, and so we can *never* have $xRx$ if $R$ is trichotomous.